# Java - How best to cycle and store values into an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have to be able to store data in a new object, that I am getting from a complex object where each item is held in a `List`.

The hierarchy is the following:

```
bookId 
pageId
wordId
```

- `bookId` is unique and can have zero to many `pageId's`
- `pageId` can have zero to many `wordId's`

I have the data, but I need to cycle through each item and put into an object - `ArrayList` or similar - so I can pass off to another class, which is expecting a `List`. In the next class, the data is to be presented in a jsp table.

Can someone please help the best way to do this. Do I need `ArrayList` or `ArrayLists`, or is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: How are you maintaining the relationship?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you need a way of cycling through and obtaining all of the wordIDs ?

Comment: How is the data presented? Is it in XML form?

Comment: Your description seems a bit complicated, so I'm not sure I quite managed to grasp it, but if you have to pass the object to a method that expects `List` and you can't change it, then yes, `ArrayList` is the simplest solution. If you can change that method, then there are probably better ways of doing it.

Comment: The data was returned in XML and passed parsed into a java object.

Comment: Yes, really I need all the wordId's

Comment: Parsed how? JAXB? If not, I would bet with proper annotations, it could work.

Comment: Yes it is JAXB with annotations

Comment: I had attempted to do this with an ArrayList and a new object. I have a advanced for loop to cycle each bookId, then inside that, an advanced for look to cycle each pageId, then inside that an advanced for loop to cycle then workId's. when I get down to the wordId's, i set bookId pageId wordId attributes in my object, then add the pbject to my ArrayList then back up to the next bookId etc. Does this sound like an ok solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way of organizing this structure is following:

```
class Book {
  int bookId;
  ArrayList<Page> pages;
}

class Page {
  int pageId;
  ArrayList<Word> words;
}

class Word {
  int wordId;
}
```

Each your entity is an object. For example Create simple book you can with next code:

```
Book book = new Book(); // create Book object
  ArrayList<Page> pages = new ArrayList<Page>;
  pages.add(new Page()); // add first page
  pages.add(new Page()); // add next page
book.setPages(pages); // set reference to pages for book
```

Note that you need provide appropriate constructors and setters/getters to operate with that code.

For presenting this data on jsp, you can use bean object Book, and with jstl you can get access to any field from book (includes each page and each word in a page) that you need.

Actually, there are lot of more complex structures but its usage depends on your requirements. I think, this model is fit for simple cases.

Comment: excellent thanks for this. I will try in the office tomorrow.

Comment: I have tried this.I am not sure I have it working correctly. This is how i have done it, based on the above answer. I the the same classes etc. I have the following data example: 1 Book, which has 1 page, which has 8 words. I have another book, which has 2 pages, each page has 6 words. I hope this makes sense. Based on the above example, how to do I write this code, and how to I then retrieve the data back out too? The aim is that I pass this to a JSP, then retieve this out into a table using JSTL <c:foreach>. Any help with this, to retrieve this data would also be helpful.

Comment: just use jstl specific accessor to bean property. For example: to print all pages from book use the following: `<c:forEach var="page" items="${book.pages}"> <!-- print page --> </c:forEach>`

Comment: thanks for this. what about my data example. how do you think this could be applied to this code above. could you help. I have the following data example: 1 Book, which has 1 page, the page has 8 words. I have another book, which has 2 pages, each page has 6 words each